# print a underscores on the basis of number of chrcters in a string python

Tags: python

How do I underline a name (produce a series of underscores based on the number of characters in the string. The output should be something like this

```
   ADARSH KUMAR
   ------------
```

GUEST LECTURER, SAVM COLLEGE

The code I have is

```
draw.text(((certificate_width - width_1)/2, 1420), line_1, fill='#666666', font=font_1)
draw.text(((certificate_width - width_2)/2, 1600), line_2, fill='#666666', font=font_2)
```

where `line_1` holds the name the length of which will vary each time

Comment: Maybe share of `methods`. It's not easy to follow what you need help with or what's not working. You even got colors there

Comment: It seems you're using a graphical package to draw lines. Are you looking to draw pixels under the names's text box? is this a txt file, pdf or something else?

Comment: i am trying to underline NAME in a certificate. The file can be both .jpg or .pdf. i am using draw.text to print name in first line and organizaion name in 2nd line. since name can contain any number of letters, the number of underlines should ne len(name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this function you can produce your underscore string based on your word

```py
def f(a):
    m = ''
    l = len(a)
    for i in range(l):
        m += '_'

    return m
```

Comment: not able to implement

Comment: It is very easy. Whats your problem??

Comment: it says m not defined!

Comment: I edit it. This because of indent in python. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

```
name=input()
for i in name:
   print('-',sep='',end='')  
#or
u_r=['-' for i in name]
print(*u_r,sep='')
```

Comment: Please include an explanation with your answer to help readers understand how this works, and solves the problem. You can click the edit button at the bottom of your answer to add an explanation. Additionally, you may find it beneficial reading [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: :( not able to implement